# Why pushing a variable containing an array inside another variable, then updating the first also updates the latter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I was studying JS when faced an unexpected behavior by me. It's probably something related to local vs global scope, however I could not find the answer. Here how it goes:

I have two arrays, one empty and another with some values. If a push the one with values inside the empty one, then updating the values using `.push()` method, it will update the array inside the other as well:

```js
let newArr = [];
let valueArr = [0,0];

newArr.push(valueArr); 
// newArr = [[0,0]]
console.log(newArr);

valueArr.push(0); 
// newArr = [0,0,0] --> updates it
console.log(valueArr);
```

However, if a now try to update the variable using `=` assignment, it won't change the array inside `newArr`

```js
let newArr = [];
let valueArr = [0,0];

newArr.push(valueArr); 
// newArr = [[0,0]]
console.log(newArr);

valueArr = [0,0,0]; 
// newArr = [[0,0]] --> does not update it
console.log(newArr);
```

Does anyone know why pushing has this behavior and reassigning does not? It's due local/global scope or when I reassign the `valueArr` variable, the `newArr` variable loses its track?

Comment: `valueArr.push(0);` pushes to the existing array, `valueArr = [0,0,0];` discards the previous reference and makes `valueArr` reference a completely new array.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with scope. When you re-assign a variable value with `=`, the previous value is gone.

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR

If you want to update `newArr`, do so explicitly:

```
valueArr = [0,0,0]; 
newArr[0] = valueArr;
```

### In depth explanation

You need to distinguish between an **object** and a **reference to object**. An object is a "thing". But a reference to an object is just a way to describe which "thing" you are talking about.

A variable is a way to explicitly reference an object using a name. But you can also reference objects in other ways, such as (as you discovered) through an array index.

A couple of important things to keep clear:

1. The [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment)(`=`) operator explicitly creates a reference to an object. You can later refer to that object through the variable name.
2. A variable can refer to different objects over time (through repeated applications of the assignment operator).
3. Arrays are JavaScript objects. You create a new array object every time you use square brackets (`[ ]`) on the right hand side of the assignment operator.
4. `a.push(b)` *implicitly* creates a reference from some index of `a` to the object being referenced by `b` at that point in time.
5. You can use the [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)(`===`) operator to determine whether two expressions refer to the same object.

```js
/* 
We create a new array, lets call it Object 1.
We can refer to that array using the variable name `a`.
*/
let a = [];
/*
We create a new array, lets call it Object 2.
We refer to that array using the variable name `b`.
*/
let b = [0];
/*
When we call `push` we are implicitly creating a 
new reference: from a[0] to Object 2.
*/
a.push(b);
/*
`a[0]` and `b` are both referring to
the *exact same* object: Object 2.
*/
console.log("Are `a[0]` and `b` the same object:", a[0] === b); // -> true

/*
We create a new array, lets call it Object 3.
We explicitly tell Javascript to use `b` to 
refer to Object 3 from this point forward.
*/
b = [2];
/*
Notice that `a[0]` still refers to Object 2.
*/
console.log("Are `a[0]` and `b` the same object:", a[0] === b); // -> false

/*
We can explicitly tell javascript to update `a` by 
using the assignment operator.
*/
a[0] = b;
console.log("Are `a[0]` and `b` the same object:", a[0] === b); // -> true
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to local/global scope.

**TLDR**

When you call `push` on an array, you add items to the existing array. When you use an assignment, you create a new array that has nothing to do with the one that was stored in the variable previously.

**Detailed**

Here's what's happening in the code:

**Step 1.** `let valueArr = [0,0];`

When you assign an array to a variable, there are two things happening:

1. An array is getting created and saved in memory(`[0,0]`)
2. The `valueArr` variable saves a reference to the created array

**Step 2.** `newArr.push(valueArr);`

Then, you push `valueArr` array into the `newArr` array. Now `newArr[0]` contains an element with the same reference as `valueArr`. They both point to the `[0,0]` array.

**Step 3.** `valueArr.push(0);`

In this step, we push an element to the array that `valueArr` references. Since `newArr` references the same array, `newArr[0]` gets updated too.

**Step 4.** `valueArr = [0,0,0];`

Here we repeat step 1. Create a new array and save its reference to the `valueArr`. The thing is that we change the reference stored in the `valueArr`, but `newArr[0]` still points to the old array. This is why you don't see any updates: it's a completely different array.

This would be a good start if you want to learn more about reference types: https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Comment: Thanks, Alex! Very elucidated answer. I think i got it now!